# Support for Arc/Info Binary Grid format by C#-bindings of GDAL

Tags: gdal, c#

I want to read Arc/Info Binary Grids and convert them to other image formats using the C#-bindings of GDAL. I installed FWTools 2.4.7 and the current binaries (MSVC2010 (Win64) -stable) from [here](http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/). Then I started testing the example C#-programs that are part of FWTools, especially GDALRead.cs and GDALReadDirect.cs. When I use the demo dataset `utm.tif`, this all works fine.

I then converted utm.tif to the Arc/Info Binary Grid format using ArcMap 10 (Conversion Tools - To Raster - Raster to other Format). When I try to use `GDALRead.cs` or `GDALReadDirect.cs` I get the following error messages:

`GDALRead.cs:`

```
Using driver Arc/Info Binary Grid
Band 1 :
DataType: GDT_Int16
Size (512,512)
PaletteInterp: GCI_Undefined
  OverView 0 :
     DataType: GDT_Int16
     Size (256,256)
     PaletteInterp: GCI_GrayIndex
  OverView 1 :
     DataType: GDT_Int16
     Size (128,128)
     PaletteInterp: GCI_GrayIndex
Non RGB images are not supported by this sample! ColorInterp = GCI_Undefined
```

`GDALReadDirect.cs:`

```
Using driver Arc/Info Binary Grid
Band 1 :
   DataType: GDT_Int16
   Size (512,512)
   PaletteInterp: GCI_Undefined
      OverView 0 :
         DataType: GDT_Int16
         Size (256,256)
         PaletteInterp: GCI_GrayIndex
      OverView 1 :
         DataType: GDT_Int16
         Size (128,128)
         PaletteInterp: GCI_GrayIndex
The number of the raster bands is not enough to run this sample
```

This behavior is a bit surprising for me, as I did not change the dataset, I simply converted it into a new format. Any hints about the reasons for this behavior and how I can use GDAL via C# to convert ArcInfo binary grids to other image formats appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GDALReadDirect.cs` has an erroneous method named `SaveBitMapDirect`, that first checks on the available Color interpretation and then on the number of bands. After the file is converted to Arc/Info binary Grid format, the information about the Color interpretation is lost, so only then the program checks on the number of available bands and returns an error message. `SaveBitMapDirect` works for the described case if Line 157 is edited:

```
if (redBand.GetRasterColorInterpretation() == ColorInterp.GCI_GrayIndex || redBand.GetRasterColorInterpretation() == ColorInterp.GCI_Undefined)
```

This is not a general fix, only for the immediate problem.